# How to delay tooltip and change autocomplete key in Visual Studio 2022 (17.3)

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, default-settings

Using Visual Studio 2022 (v17.3) Community Edition.

I would like to customize my experience by:

- Changing the default "accept" key for `autocomplete` suggestions from `Tab` to `Space`
- Change the `tooltip` interval. (Right now, it seems tooltips are activated instantaneously with no delay whatsoever. Ideally, I would like to set it to 1000ms)

I've looked in the editor options but couldn't find anything related to the preferences I am trying to change.